# cd displays the list of files and folders in macOS

Tags: mac, bash-alias

Recently I have updated macOS and Terminal and below is the details

- macOS Sierra *10.12.6*
- Command Line Tool Version *9.0*

Now whenever I run `cd` in the Terminal it navigated to that directory and automatically list out all the directory structure which I do not want (by default).

How can I fix that? I think culprit may be the alias but do not know how to fix it and here is my bash_profile setting.

#### ~/.bash_profile

```
alias cp='cp -iv'                           # Preferred 'cp' implementation
alias mv='mv -iv'                           # Preferred 'mv' implementation
alias mkdir='mkdir -pv'                     # Preferred 'mkdir' implementation
alias ll='ls -FGlAhp'                       # Preferred 'ls' implementation
alias less='less -FSRXc'                    # Preferred 'less' implementation
cd() { builtin cd "$@"; ll; }               # Always list directory contents upon 'cd'
alias cd..='cd ../'                         # Go back 1 directory level (for fast typers)
alias ..='cd ../'                           # Go back 1 directory level
alias ...='cd ../../'                       # Go back 2 directory levels
alias .3='cd ../../../'                     # Go back 3 directory levels
alias .4='cd ../../../../'                  # Go back 4 directory levels
alias .5='cd ../../../../../'               # Go back 5 directory levels
alias .6='cd ../../../../../../'            # Go back 6 directory levels
alias edit='subl'                           # edit:         Opens any file in sublime editor
alias f='open -a Finder ./'                 # f:            Opens current directory in MacOS Finder
alias ~="cd ~"                              # ~:            Go Home
alias c='clear' 
alias qfind="find . -name "                 # qfind:    Quickly search for file
ff () { /usr/bin/find . -name "$@" ; }      # ff:       Find file under the current directory
ffs () { /usr/bin/find . -name "$@"'*' ; }  # ffs:      Find file whose name starts with a given string
ffe () { /usr/bin/find . -name '*'"$@" ; }  # ffe:      Find file whose name ends with a given string
alias psgrep='ps aux | grep '
```

Comment: found the solution. comment the line `#cd()` in `.bash_profile .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .bash_profile file you have set `cd` to always display the directory contents.

Comment the line

`cd() { builtin cd "$@"; ll; }               # Always list directory contents upon 'cd'`

to avoid this behavior.